# Calling any Ruby class in Mini_Test and Uninitialized Constant Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I want to make DCI implementation by using Mini_Test and Ruby, but I couldn't call AcademicYear class in Mini_Test.  I have a simple class and Mini_Test class in seperated files like below;

**/app/Models/academicyear.rb**

```
class AcademicYear
  attr_accessor :year
end
```

**/app/Test/Contexts/headteacher_define_academicyear_context_test.rb**

```
require "minitest_helper"
class HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContextTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_should_add_academic_year
    academicyear = AcademicYear.new
    academicyear.year= "2012-2013"
  end
end
```

When I create a new AcademicYear object I got this error;

```
HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContextTest#test_should_add_academic_year:
NameError: uninitialized constant HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContextTest::AcademicYear
    /home/developer/Desktop/dciexample/test/contexts/headteacher_define_academicyear_context_test.rb:6:in `test_should_add_academic_year'
```

What I am missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to require your class

```
require_relative '../../Models/academicyear.rb'
```

as result you have

`/app/Test/Contexts/headteacher_define_academicyear_context_test.rb`

```
require "minitest_helper"
require_relative '../../Models/academicyear.rb'

class HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContextTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_should_add_academic_year
    academicyear = AcademicYear.new
    academicyear.year= "2012-2013"
  end
end
```